# Best place to call xdebug helper functions?

Tags: debug, customization

Right now I place the following code wherever I expect something to go wrong.

```
/** xdebug helper */
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    ini_set("html_errors", 1);
```

Where should I include this code so that it's always called on every page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They recommend putting it into the wp-config.php file.

You can read more about it from the codex [Editing wp-config](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

It is quite a long document but the error info is found at **2.15 Configure Error Logging**

Comment: "_This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content_", which I am sure you don't want. I know. The nature of the question makes for a short answer but try to elaborate. Who recommends, for example?